# Implementing Audio Recording With an ARKit Module- Swift

Tags: swift, uikit, arkit, avaudioplayer

I am looking to implement audio recording and sending the audio file to an API endpoint for processing in swift, the problem I am having is that I have the ARKit Framework basically as the whole app. I was wondering if I could get some guidance as to how to implement Audio recording, by allowing the user to start recording by holding down on a UI button and stop when they stop interacting with the button. Below is my code, its all in the ViewController.swift file.

```
import UIKit
import ARKit
extension BinaryInteger {
    var degreesToRadians: CGFloat { CGFloat(self) * .pi / 180 }
}

extension FloatingPoint {
    var degreesToRadians: Self { self * .pi / 180 }
    var radiansToDegrees: Self { self * 180 / .pi }
}
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var sceneView: ARSCNView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        addTapGestureToSceneView()
        
        configureLighting()
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        setUpSceneView()
    }
    
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        sceneView.session.pause()
    }
    
    func setUpSceneView() {
        let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
        configuration.planeDetection = .horizontal
        
        sceneView.session.run(configuration)
        
        sceneView.delegate = self
        sceneView.debugOptions = [ARSCNDebugOptions.showFeaturePoints]
    }
    
    func configureLighting() {
        sceneView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true
        sceneView.automaticallyUpdatesLighting = true
    }
    
    @objc func addShipToSceneView(withGestureRecognizer recognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        var totalRotation: Float = 0.0
        let tapLocation = recognizer.location(in: sceneView)
        let hitTestResults = sceneView.hitTest(tapLocation, types: .existingPlaneUsingExtent)
        
        guard let hitTestResult = hitTestResults.first else { return }
        let translation = hitTestResult.worldTransform.translation
        let x = translation.x
        let y = translation.y
        let z = translation.z
        
        guard let shipScene = SCNScene(named: "kim.scn"),
            let shipNode = shipScene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "high_poly", recursively: false)
            else { return }
        shipNode.scale = SCNVector3(2, 2, 2)
        // Rotate the model by 90 degrees on the y-axis
        // Rotate the model by 90 degrees on the y-axis
        totalRotation += Float(270).degreesToRadians
        shipNode.eulerAngles.y = totalRotation


        
        
        shipNode.position = SCNVector3(x,y,z)
        sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(shipNode)
    }
    
    func addTapGestureToSceneView() {
        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.addShipToSceneView(withGestureRecognizer:)))
        sceneView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
    }
}

extension float4x4 {
    var translation: float3 {
        let translation = self.columns.3
        return float3(translation.x, translation.y, translation.z)
    }
}

extension UIColor {
    open class var transparentLightBlue: UIColor {
        return UIColor(red: 90/255, green: 200/255, blue: 250/255, alpha: 0.50)
    }
}

extension ViewController: ARSCNViewDelegate {
    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
        // 1
        guard let planeAnchor = anchor as? ARPlaneAnchor else { return }
        
        // 2
        let width = CGFloat(planeAnchor.extent.x)
        let height = CGFloat(planeAnchor.extent.z)
        let plane = SCNPlane(width: width, height: height)
        
        // 3
        plane.materials.first?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.transparentLightBlue
        
        // 4
        let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
        
        // 5
        let x = CGFloat(planeAnchor.center.x)
        let y = CGFloat(planeAnchor.center.y)
        let z = CGFloat(planeAnchor.center.z)
        planeNode.position = SCNVector3(x,y,z)
        planeNode.eulerAngles.x = -.pi / 2
        
        // 6
        node.addChildNode(planeNode)
    }
    
    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didUpdate node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
        // 1
        guard let planeAnchor = anchor as?  ARPlaneAnchor,
            let planeNode = node.childNodes.first,
            let plane = planeNode.geometry as? SCNPlane
            else { return }
        
        // 2
        let width = CGFloat(planeAnchor.extent.x)
        let height = CGFloat(planeAnchor.extent.z)
        plane.width = width
        plane.height = height
        
        // 3
        let x = CGFloat(planeAnchor.center.x)
        let y = CGFloat(planeAnchor.center.y)
        let z = CGFloat(planeAnchor.center.z)
        planeNode.position = SCNVector3(x, y, z)
    }
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated!